# HTML Content not showing up despite appearing in the html source

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php file called randompage.php which will display all laptops based on the user's selection on the sidebar. If user ticks Microsoft, all Microsoft laptops will appear. I think it may have something to do with CSS, but I'm not sure.

**randompage.php**

```
<section class="products bg-light">

<section class="display_product row">

</section>

<section class="product_filter">
<section class="sidebar-box-2">

 <h2 class="heading mb-8">Brand</h2>
 <section class="product-filter-item checkbox">
 <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="<?php
 echo sanitize($brand);?>"> <?php echo sanitize($brand);?></label>
 </section>

 </section>
 </section>
 </section>
```

**fetch_data.php**

```
if (
   $selectproductsstatement &&
   $selectproductsstatement->execute() &&
   $selectproductsstatement->store_result()&&
   $selectproductsstatement->bind_result($product_name,$brand,$processor,$os,$memory,$hard_disk,$battery,$weight,$price)
    ) {
    while ($selectproductsstatement->fetch()) {
    $output .= '<dl class="product col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ftco-animate">//Huge chunk of content';</dl>
           }
      }

else
{
    $output = 'No Data Found';
}
echo $output;
```

**CSS**:

```
section.products.bg-light {
    padding: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    display: inherit;
}
section.display_product {
    width: 85%;
    float: right;
}

section.product_filter {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Data being written into section.display_product.row

[image]

Empty page:
[image]

Comment: Something in your CSS is hiding/moving but it will be very difficult for us to assist. I'd try commenting out chunks of CSS until you figure out the responsible section. Go from there.

Answer (score 0):

your `dl` elements are using this class `.ftco-animate` it sets the `opactiy: 0;` and `visibility: hidden;`

This hides the images and text for your products.

Remove the class for showing your products.

```
.ftco-animate {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```